# What deselect selected cell when navigationController pops a view?

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

The default NavigationController template offered by apple, it has one navigationController and a table.

And if you select a cell, a new view will be pushed into navigationController and if you pop the view, the selected cell will be de-hightlighted automatically.

But how does table know when to de-hightlight it and how does it know which cell is selected??

or does it just re-load all data again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how does table know when to de-hightlight it

You can deselect your cell right in selection handler:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    ...
}
```

or reset selection in controller's `-viewWillAppear:` method

> and how does it know which cell is selected?

UITableView has the following method to get selected row indexPath:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3.0**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    if self.yourTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow != nil
    {
        self.yourTableView.deselectRow(at: self.yourTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

This code will avoid the **Crash** as well...

Also, add the below line in the other ViewController whom you're pushing while selecting a TableViewCell.

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
```

Works like a Charm =]

Hope it helps..